# Can a M1 MacBook Air come with macOS Monterey pre-installed?

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, auto-update

I recently bought an M1 MacBook Air and according to all sources I could find it is supposed to come with macOS Big Sur installed.

However I noticed that my MacBook already came with macOS Monterey installed out of the box! Is this possible?

Bonus Question: Can anyone find a video which shows the first boot sequence without any cuts so that I can compare it to my first boot?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A new Mac will always come with the latest version of macOS available when manufactured.  So I would expect any new Mac to come with macOS 12.4, 12.3 or perhaps 12.2 (Monterey).  And you should update it to 12.4.

The confusion with Big Sur is because when the M1 MBA was first released it came with, and required, macOS 11 (Big Sur).

Comment: Can you provide any citations for this? I've never read about this and even Apple support denied this, so I'm skeptical.

Comment: @John Apple doesn't keep selling models on last year's OS. At some point, the factory 'golden master' image will be updated. For instance, the 2012 13" MBP was sold for over 4 years. They didn't keep selling it with the original OS.

Comment: @John All the Apple pages about the MBA (e.g. https://www.apple.com/au/macbook-air/) show it with Monterey.  I would be a bit suspicious that it was old stock if it came with older macOS - and be checking age of battery!

Comment: Ah, okay! Thank you for confirming benwiggy and Gilby